# Open Jquery Dialog Server Side

Tags: asp.net, jquery, user-interface

Is it available to open jquery Dialog Server Side From Behind Code in asp.net?
Please give me an example or a link for more information. 
thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [RegisterStartupScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/asz8zsxy.aspx) method from the code behind:

```
public void SomeButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string script = "$('#someid').dialog('open');";
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "popup", script, true);
}
```

But mixing javascript and c# code is a very clean approach. It would be better to simply open the dialog from javascript on the client.

Comment: Thanks. So I want to show Dialog after Postback. Is it possible? thanks

Comment: You could use the `$(document).ready` function but include it only if it is a postback: `<% if (IsPostBack) { ... %>`